# Importing e-mails and attachments into a database

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, email, parsing

I've searched around a little bit and can't seem to find anything super useful on how to do this. I would like to be able to set up an email account which is able to receive emails and parse them into a database which will be useable later.  What I would like would be to have a Database which linked the Sender, Subject, and attachment together at minimum, and maybe email the sender with an automated response if the database was successfully updated.

Thanks for any help you can provide in getting me started with this!

Answer (score 1):

If you are mainly storing emails then you probably either want this: http://archiveopteryx.org or this: http://www.dbmail.org/

If you want to send emails with "commands" or "updates" for your database to process then read up on [procmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail) and whatever MIME-parsing library your favourite language supports. Note that MIME can be fiddly, so allow time to understand the problem.